# How can I return my def class object to my def main in python?

Tags: python, class, cs50

I have my code for implementing a program that calculates the grade level needed to comprehend some text (You might know CS50)

I try to implement a class object even though it may not be necessary. But I'm practicing with it. Anyway, could you maybe have a look and tell me where I am wrong and it can't work like that? Can you maybe give me some improvements?

Thank you very much for your help.

Ah, and the code goes on with actually doing some iteration to actually filter the text from input (for example read the spaces and so on). But first it's about this issue.

When I add values in Read() --> TypeError: **init**() should return None, not 'function'
Without values I get --> TypeError: Read.**init**() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'text_num', 'space_count', and 'marks_count'

```
# import libary
import cs50

def main():

   read = Read()

   aver_letters_words = round(read.text_num / read.space_count * 100)
   aver_sent_words = round(read.marks_count / read.space_count * 100)

   # Adding the variables into the Coleman-Liau index formula
   index = 0.0588 * aver_letters_words - 0.296 * aver_sent_words - 15.8

   #Checking the limits of the grade level via if-statement
   if index < 1:
       print("Before Grade 1")
   elif index >= 16:
       print("Grade 16+")
   else:
       print("Grade", index)



class Read():
    def __init__(self, text_num, space_count, marks_count):
        self.text_num = text_num
        self.space_count = space_count
        self.marks_count = marks_count

#read = Read()
#print(read.text_num)

    return main
```

main()

Comment: What are you expecting `return main` to even *do*?

Comment: You really need some very basic tutorial on OOP/class in python.

Comment: To make the class "usable". Well to be honest i'm a little confused by https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/returning-a-function-from-a-function-python/ - In C I have a quite different understanding about that

Comment: What does the link you reference to the problem with the `__init__` method in your class returning a function? What does it mean "to make class usable"?Again - you need a basic tutorial on class/OOP in python - the whole code is a mess - e.g. you don't understand why it complains that you need to pass arguments at class instantiation

Comment: Hi guys, thanks but I know that I need more practing. But I do know that I have to pass arguments etc, no question about it. I know I have to initialize them and the like read = Read(10, 11, 12) -> print() or what ever. I just try to take them as a source for a further calculation like Daniel did below. And I'm just from C where I did something similar with structs. So it's not that helpful if you tell me I need a basic tutorial. I am in a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the python interpreter is rather precise with the error description given here. Also, I believe you have two independent errors here.

Firstly: `init() should return None, not 'function'`. You have a `return main` at the end of your class definition, which returns a function `main`. I don't quite understand what are you trying to achieve, but get rid of this line to remove the first problem.

As for the second bug, `TypeError: Read.init() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'text_num', 'space_count', and 'marks_count'`. You have defined the `Read().__init__` method with three arguments, but while creating the object in line 6, you try to create the `Read()` object without any of them. Either specify some default values in the `__init__` or provide the positional arguments in line 6.

Finally, since you are using the `Read` class to store data only, I would suggest using a `dict` or a `dataclass` (Python 3.7+) instead.
For the latter, see: https://realpython.com/python-data-classes/.

---

If I understand your intents correctly, a python solution to your problem might look something like below:

```
class Text():
    def __init__(self, text_num, space_count, marks_count):
        self.text_num = text_num
        self.space_count = space_count
        self.marks_count = marks_count
    
    def evaluate():
        aver_letters_words = round(read.text_num / read.space_count * 100)
        index = 0.0588 * aver_letters_words - 0.296 * aver_sent_words - 15.8
        if index < 1:
            print("Before Grade 1")
        elif index >= 16:
            print("Grade 16+")
        else:
            print("Grade", index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Text(12, 1, 1)  # input here manually for text 'Hello world!'
    t.evaluate()        # this prints the output
```